# naiveBayes giving unexpected result when passed 1 document instead of many

Tags: r

I have the following code which works perfectly well:

```
news_classifier <- naiveBayes(news_train, news_raw_train$type)
news_test_pred <- predict(news_classifier, news_test)
```

In this context, `news_test` is defined as follows:

```
news_test <- DocumentTermMatrix(news_corpus_test, control = list(dictionary = news_dict))
news_test <- apply(news_test, MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)
```

`news_corpus_test` contains some several hundred documents.

My problem is, I am now trying to only pass but one document to the `predict()` method and have it tell me what it is.  I proceed as follows:

```
# first, I pass a vector containing the words which I know will be found in
# in my news_dict
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(c('life dog women')))

corpus_clean1 <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus_clean1 <- tm_map(corpus_clean1, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
corpus_clean1 <- tm_map(corpus_clean1, removePunctuation)
corpus_clean1 <- tm_map(corpus_clean1, stripWhitespace)

inspect(corpus_clean1)
```

Inspected corpus outputs this:

```
> inspect(corpus_clean1)
<<VCorpus (documents: 1, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
life dog women
```

Then, I create the DTM like so:

```
test <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus_clean1, control = list(dictionary = news_dict))
test <- apply(test, MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)

test
```

Which outputs this:

```
> test
      after        back        beat        bill      brazil      bridge         can     cantors         car        cave 
         No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No 
    circles     climate         cup        cuts         dog       egypt       fairy forecasters        game     germany 
         No          No          No          No         Yes          No          No          No          No          No 
        get       group        hits         how        iraq       iraqi     israeli        kill       kills         kim 
         No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No 
       life        loss        make         man   militants    namibias       obama        open    pakistan      photos 
        Yes          No          No          No          No          No         Yes          No          No          No 
      plane      police   president        rail republicans        says      school      strike         the       trial 
         No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No 
    ukraine    violence       visit        vote       watch     weather        week       white         who        will 
         No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No          No 
        win       woman     workers       world     yearold 
         No          No          No          No          No 
Levels: No Yes
```

And, finally, I run the `predict()` method:

```
test_pred <- predict(news_classifier, test)
test_pred
```

Which outputs this:

```
> test_pred
 [1] neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral
[16] neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral
[31] neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral
[46] neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral
[61] neutral neutral neutral neutral neutral
Levels: negative neutral positive
```

However, I don't expect all that.  Rather, I expect for there to be a single value returned i.e. neutral, positive, or negative.

Why isn't the predict method returning as I would expect?

**Edit:** Here is the `convert_counts()` method:

```
# convert > 0 to factor Yes/No
convert_counts <- function(x) {
  x <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
  x <- factor(x, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("No", "Yes"))
  return (x)
}
```

**Edit:** Here are the packages I am using:

```
# get text mining package
install.packages("tm")
library(tm)
# get e1071 package for naive bayes classifier
install.packages("e1071")
library(e1071)
# get gmodels
library(gmodels)
```

Comment: Could you post the function convert_counts?

Comment: @Ravi Sure, the question now contains it.

Comment: Are these base R functions? No. So please provide reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this the most elegant solution but I think this should work:

```
    test <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus_clean1, control = list(dictionary = news_dict))
    test <- data.frame(as.matrix(test))
    test <- data.frame(lapply(test,convert_counts))
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks, it does work.  Why does this work vs. what I had?  Don't really understand.

Comment: When you pass a DTM matrix/data frame with several documents to the apply function and call covert_counts, it returns a matrix/data frame. However, when you pass the DTM with just one document, it returns a vector. Each one of those elements is treated as a document and prediction is done for each. However, when we use lapply, the result is returned as a list which can then be coerced into a data frame. See if the following example helps:                                 M <- data.frame(matrix(seq(1,16), 4, 4))
t1 <- apply(M,2,sum)
t2 <- lapply(M,sum)